# Problema a la hora de validar un formulario con javascript

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

El problema que tengo es que cuando intento validar mi formulario, quiero que valide primero el campo nombre.
Pero a la hora de ejecutar el código, valida del campo descripción.

Otro problema que noté es que si cambio del lugar el llamado de las funciones siempre valida primero al última que llamé.

```
const form = document.querySelector("#form-proyecto");
const solo_letras = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$", "i");

let nombre = form.nombre;
let descripcion = form.descripcion;

form.addEventListener("submit", validar);
function validar(e) {

  validarNombre(e);
  validarDescripcion(e);
}

function validarNombre(e) {
  if (
    nombre.value == "" ||  nombre.value == null ||  nombre.value.length < 3 || !solo_letras.test(nombre.value)) {
    Swal.fire(
      "Aviso",
      "El campo nombre es obligatorio,<br> debe tener como mínimo 3 caracteres y <br>solo se aceptan letras",
      "error"
    );
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function validarDescripcion(e) {
  if (
    descripcion.value == "" || descripcion.value == null || descripcion.value.length < 20 ) {
    Swal.fire(
      "Aviso",
      "El campo descripción es obligatorio y<br>debe tener como mínimo 20 caracteres",
      "error"
    );
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans) puedes ver como formatear tu código en las preguntas y respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

podrias encadenar los `if`, asi siempre vas a estar seguro que primero pasa por una condicion, si no se cumple continua con la siguiente, y si se cumple, se queda ahi.

```js
function validar(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  if(nombre.value == "" ||  nombre.value == null ||  nombre.value.length < 3 || !solo_letras.test(nombre.value)){
    Swal.fire(
      "Aviso",
      "El campo nombre es obligatorio,<br> debe tener como mínimo 3 caracteres y <br>solo se aceptan letras",
      "error"
    );
  }else if(descripcion.value == "" || descripcion.value == null || descripcion.value.length < 20){
    Swal.fire(
      "Aviso",
      "El campo descripción es obligatorio y<br>debe tener como mínimo 20 caracteres",
      "error"
    );
  }
}
```

espero que esto te ayude.